# Website recieves "undefined" messages post deployment only some of the time

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest, undefined, nodemailer

I have built and hosted a website with node js, html, css and javascript. On the website there is a contact form for the user to fill out with some fields.

After the user fills it out and presses the send button, i send a post xml http request to the node server with a json containing user info.

That info then gets sent to a gmail via nodemailer in this format:

```
Name: (First & last name)
Email: (Email)
.
.
.
```

When i test everything or have friends try to use the website from all possible browsers, everything works just fine with 0 errors and warnings and i recieve their exact input.

However, ever sine the website has been put up i keep recieving this message a couple of times a day:

```
Name: undefined
Email: undefined
.
.
.
```

So i was just wondering if anyone else has encountered a similar issue as i don't even know where to begin since there is no way to reproduce the issue on my end?

Comment: you need to figure out where the `undefined` is coming from. use `console.log` to see if the name and email are undefined at the frontend or backend.

Edit: have you setup validation on your website? for example, if the user doesn't fill the form but hits submit then what happens? it should display an error

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! Due to the fact that the message stays in the same format except with undefined in place of user text and the very specific way i set it up. I know the problem has to be with the frontend javascript. I use pm2 to run the server code in the background, do you know of a way to see console.log when pm2 is running?

Comment: My main problem is that i have tried to reproduce the error a million times and never gotten an undefined. If the issue is on the client side, what would be the best way to log that?

Comment: By client if you mean the frontend, then using `console.log` you can log any variable and see it's value in the dev tools of your browser. I'm unaware of pm2

Comment: It gives an alert to the user that they have to fill out all of the fields.

Comment: Thats why the problem is so wierd, i have done that and no matter what input i tried or what browser i have never gotten that error on my end. Its unreproducable. I have gotten 10 different people to fill out the form on the actual website too, multiple times, still no error. Its almost as if a spam bot is writing undefined in the fields just to mess with me.

Comment: The site works perfect on chrome, safari, firefox and edge. Both mobile and desktop.

Comment: Search for ways to log your backend, i dont know about pm2 so you need to search. Even if this error occurs sometimes, with logging you can track down the problem area

Comment: Ok, thank you. Really appreciate the help, i'll make an update if i find the solution.

Comment: `Its almost as if a spam bot is writing undefined in the fields just to mess with me.` - or to send out spam emails using your mailer.  Have you checked your server logs?  Is the "page that receives the form" being hit without the "page that has the form" first being served?